Solving logistic regression using CVXPY
I am trying to code a logistic regression model using the CVXPY library. The code I have written so far "works" in the sense that it can be executed, it does not yield any error message and provides a solution. However, this solution does not match the solution provided by the scikit-learn implementation of logistic regression.
I know scikit-learns implementation includes an L2 penalty by default, and in the code example below you will see that I changed this to None. Also I removed the intercept from the sklearn model. But still the solutions do not match:
import cvxpy as cp
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

X, y = make_classification(n_features=10, random_state=42)

sk = LogisticRegression(penalty=None, fit_intercept=False)
sk.fit(X, y)
print(sk.coef_)

This produces the output:
[[-13.46939518  -7.09935934  19.41989522 -10.36990818   3.76335965
2.84616038   3.32474461  -2.84162961   3.13246888   1.08887971]]

Now, the cvxpy implementation:
beta = cp.Variable(X.shape[1])
log_likelihood = cp.sum(cp.multiply(y, X @ beta) - cp.logistic(X @ beta))
problem = cp.Problem(cp.Maximize(log_likelihood/X.shape[0]))
problem.solve()
beta = beta.value
print(beta)

produces the solution:
[-31.38130594 -10.72178524  44.07489985 -34.06127916   8.01950276
   5.96941765   9.6143194   -7.88785049  12.96349703  -0.13264449]

EDIT:
The log likelihood formula my code is solving is
$$
\ell(\beta)=\sum_{i=1}^m y_i \beta^T x_i-\log \left(1+\exp \left(\beta^T x_i\right)\right)
$$

can you provide the log likelihood mathematical formula your code should implement? because it doesn't look like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression

There must be a typographical error in your log likelihood, because (1) in general that expression won't have a maximum and (2) it doesn't correspond at all to logistic regression.

Thank you for your comment. Starting from the Likelihood function for logistic regression and using some basic algebra will lead you to this equation. However, if I define the objective function as strictly the log likelihood with no other transformation, the original question remains. Scikit- learn provides a solution that is different than that of cvxpy.

Cross-posted at https://stackoverflow.com/q/78892162/10495893

I upvoted @whuber's comment because the likelihood looked suspicious to me at first too. But looking more closely, I think it does work out to be equivalent to what I'm used to seeing presented. Hm.

@BenReiniger this loglik expression can be derived from the canonical parameterization of the bernoulli.

There are two issues: computational precision issues with well-separated classes, and multicolinearity.

To the first one, check out the predicted probabilities from the model on your dataset (er, the version of the dataset generated by your code in my environment):
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.hist(sk.predict_proba(X)[:, 1], bins=100);


The two classes are easily separated, and so the coefficients can be very large, but the specific values aren't very important.  At some point, different handling of numerical precision by the two packages accounts for the difference in coefficients, but predicted probabilities are all very close to 0 and 1 (predicted log-odds, the linear part of the regression, are very large in absolute value).
You can get something nicer by reducing the separability of the classes in the data generator, e.g. by setting class_sep=0.1.  Coefficients are much smaller and closer together, though not quite the same without the next bit.

The other thing is that make_classification also creates some features as linear combinations of others.  In that case, the coefficients among those features can fluctuate and still produce the same model, provided the sum of the coefficients is correct.  (I'm not positive whether that's strictly true here, or if additional noise gets added by make_classification; but it's close enough to mislead the solver I suppose.)  Setting n_redundant=0 fixes this.

The two fixes together give me the same coefficients to enough decimal places to make me happy:
# sklearn
[ 5.2359204  -0.23772338  0.20518891 -4.11765885  0.09401551  0.24242961
 -0.33076897  0.67412935  0.18312105  0.15458342]
# cvxpy
[ 5.23590348 -0.23772127  0.20519077 -4.11764086  0.09401678  0.24242913
 -0.33076891  0.67412387  0.18311638  0.15458151]

